# Getting 'the macros in this project are disabled message' when trying to run Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

All of a sudden I am getting this message.

[image]

I had to do a system restore recently, and everything came back pretty much as I expected, with some tweaks of course, but now I'm getting a weird message from MS Outlook, which I have never seen before. Before posting here, I Googled this issue and came up with this potential solution, which didn't work.

File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Macro Settings > Enable All Macros

I'm still seeing the same error message...'the macros in this project are disabled'

How can I get this code working once again? I don't think it's a code issue, I think it's a permissions issue.

Comment: Did you try restarting Outlook after making the change?

Comment: What Windows version are you running?

Comment: @jxramos That looks like a Windows 10 UI in the screenshot.

Comment: steps for an older version of outlook: https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-do-i-enable-macros-in-outlook-2003.854025/#post-14115111

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After making changes in the Trust center of Outlook you need to restart the host application to make the changes permanent.